# IIS 7 Service Unavailable 503 ERROR

Tags: iis-7, fastcgi, http-status-code-503

I am encountering a 503 - Service Unavailable error. I checked the event log and found this:

> The Module name FastCgiModule path
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll
>   returned an error from registration. 
>   The data is the error.

Note: Every time I try to visit my website, I found that the DefaultAppPool will auto-stop.
And also found this in event log:

> Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is
>   being automatically disabled due to a
>   series of failures in the process(es)
>   serving that application pool.

Answer (score 9):

This is because your application pool is crashing more than 5 times in 5 minutes [default settings - Rapid Fail]

Instead of disabling Rapid Fail, you should consider taking Crash Dumps and try to find out the root cause. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/02/what-is-a-crash-technically-in-asp-net-and-what-to-do-if-it-happens.aspx