# How to automatically run files under app_start folder if published using webdeploy

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment, webdeploy, app-startup

IN my asp.net MVC4 project I have few .cs files under the app_start folder that needs to be initialized or perform per-authorization tasks etc. When you access the website they take quite a lot of time to perform all these tasks on application start for first time. Is it possible to run all files under app_start folder automatically while deployment. So that when someone access the website for the first time it wont take that much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [auto-starting your application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Add this to your applicationHost.config

```
<sites>    
     <site name="MySite" id="1">    
          <application path="/" 
                       serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" 
                       serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache" />    
     </site>    
</sites>
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
     <add name="PreWarmMyCache" type="PreWarmCache, MyAssembly" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

and the following to preload your work

```
public class PreWarmCache : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient {

    public void Preload(string[] parameters) {

        // Perform initialization and cache loading logic here...

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, Can you please confirm do I have to add this in web.config as you are saying or in applicationHost.config file as explained in your referred link.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please also guide Do I have to replace my  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    { protected void Application_Start() with the public class PreWarmCache : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient {

Comment: No it does not replace.  It's a separate class and it can put it in the root of your web app or wherever you want so long as the serviceAutoStartProviders configuration namespace matches.

Comment: Thanks dave, Performed all steps but getting Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. Any idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: something is very wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420869/iis-7-service-unavailable-503-error  double check all config settings and steps in that article.  try applying one change at a time until it breaks.